# How do I keep actions and animations running during a scene transition in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a retry button, that is rotating, that when pressed, presents a new scene using `GameView.presentScene(GameScene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2))`. While this transition occurs, the rotation stops. My aim is to keep the button rotating, until the GameScene is fully presented. If it helps, this is all done in a SpriteKit based game. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891863/how-to-keep-skactions-running-through-an-sktransition-in-sprite-kit/24892967#24892967

Answer (score 3):

Set the `pausesOutgoingScene` property on the transition object to false.

```
var transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2)
transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false
//transition.pausesIncomingScene = false //Uncomment if you want both to animate
GameView.presentScene(GameScene, transition: transition )
```

Comment: Awesome, I didnt even know about this, I guess I should read more of apples documents. I just answered the OPs question but will edit my answer now because yours is clearly better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You always learn something on stack overflow, thanks KnightOfDragon for your answer which is much better than my answer.

You could use UIKit elements

Make a global property

```
 unlockButton: UIButton!
```

and set it up in your scene

```
 unlockButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    unlockButton.frame = CGRectMake(width * 2, height * 2, width, height)
    unlockButton.backgroundColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    unlockButton.layer.borderColor = SKColor.blackColor().CGColor
    unlockButton.layer.borderWidth = DeviceManager.convertCGFloat(1)
    unlockButton.layer.cornerRadius = DeviceManager.convertCGFloat(2)
    unlockButton.setTitle("ButtonTitle", forState: .Normal)
    unlockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 14)
    unlockButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    unlockButton.addTarget(self, action: "unlockButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(unlockButton)
```

Than use something like

```
 CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
```

and

```
 UIView animateWithDuration
```

to make it rotate.

Than once the transition has finished you should be able to remove it with

```
 unlockButton.removeFromSuperView()
```

from the new scene.